# Automatically scroll down with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal box with a defined height. Inside of this box there is an accordion box that expands when a user clicks a link. The height of the accordion box when it is toggled exceeds the height of the modal box and thus a scrollbar appears.

I would like to automatically scroll the bars down to its lowest point to display the new content in the accordion box.

The accordian box looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
$(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to integrate this scroll down function into the existing function? Is there an existing Jquery function for this type of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on any plugin, or change the actual URL, you could use scrollTop, see http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Cheers.

Comment: I thought about this, but the content is dynamic, so I am unsure what the hieght will be.

Comment: You should have a reference to the wanted element, so you could use $(window).scrollTop( $(wantedelement).offset().top ) -- If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ok so I set it up like this:

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
$(window).scrollTop( $("#no").offset().top )
});
});

#no is a the the very bottom of my accordion panel. This doesn't seem to fire. Have I set it up correctly?

Comment: Seems to work for me here; http://jsfiddle.net/ZuBZT/ in Chrome. According to the comments on the API site, `scrollTop` can be a little dodgy. You'll have to try with different selectors (although, `window` seems best), here's another one that people seem to use: `$('body,html')`

Comment: Thanks for making an example to look at - Im still having trouble with it. Using your code, I put together my situation here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZuBZT/10/

Comment: Hm, might be an issue with $(window) (and jsfiddle); try this one: http://jsbin.com/ifege

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're looking for...

If you'd like a nice smooth scroll, then the [scollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) is a great choice.

If you don't care, just use a hash. location.hash = '#someid';

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I am looking for. I don't really care about any animation, I just need to get down there when the accordion triggers. I would like to avoid using some extra plugin if possible though.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use an outer container-div which is scrollable. This allows to find out the size of the inner div which holds the actual content.
My solution (You have to do some adjustments for your accordion):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #container {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 200px; /* defined height */
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <div id="content">
            <!-- dynamic content -->
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function onNewContent() {
         $("#container").scrollTop($("#content").height());
      }

      //test
      $(document).ready(function() {
         for(var i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
            $("#content").append($("<div/>").html(i));
         onNewContent();
      });
   </script>
</html>
```