# Creating a chat box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, chat

I want a chat box logic like Facebook in my website. When user types a chat message it should be added to the end of chat box and top message should be scrolled upside. I created a div and try to scroll it using jQuery Scroll function. But its not working. Please someone help...

my html code

```
<div class="cnt">
try
</div>
```

my jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.cnt').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
    });
});​
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code for what you've tried.

Comment: If it's all about scrolling down, here a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346819/automatically-scroll-down-with-jquery

Comment: actually I want this http://jsfiddle.net/AsWyk/ but text should be scrolled up from bottom instead of up to down.

Answer (score 0):

you need to study on comet [Comet Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). also  HTML5 provides [ServerSentEvents](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)